# Neo4j duplicate records issue

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am facing issues of duplicate recoreds on simple query. In my database, i have some countries data and countries points to organization types. I am fetching countries and organizations, database giving me duplicate records in both country and organization types.

Query

```
MATCH (n:OrganizationType),(c:Country) RETURN n,c LIMIT 25
```

Tried also with distinct

```
MATCH (n:OrganizationType),(c:Country) RETURN distinct n,c LIMIT 25
```

Graphical view of records

[image]

Please help me what i am missing here ?

Comment: It would help to know exactly what you are trying to return (what data, what format). Do you just want the total of all countries and organizations? Do you want, for each country, all of its organizations? Or for all organizations, what countries they operate in? Or something completely different?

Comment: I just want to return all the countries and organizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning *pairs* of (organization, country), and when you put `DISTINCT` on it, it just ensures that the *pair* is distinct. When building queries, don't think of "returning records", but of "generating result rows". If you want to generate result rows that contain 1 node, which is either a Country or an Organization, and you want every Country or Organization to get 1 row, up to 25 total rows, try a simple query like this:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n:Country OR n:Organization
RETURN n LIMIT 25
```